# how to open sql files

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 2 files, please can anyone advise me on how i can open and access these files.

**Name**             **Type**
Counties             Sql Server primary data file
Countries_log        Sql server database transaction log file

Thanks

Comment: First, run Notepad. Click the File menu, then select Open. Now browse to and double click your .sql file.

Comment: Do you want to run them against a database, or open them so you can read them?

Comment: Right click (may need to hold down shift too), select "Open With" and select Notepad

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have SQL Server Management Studio you should be able to attach them with the attach command. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190209.aspx

If you don't you can download express versions from Microsoft.
http://www.microsoft.com/express/Database/InstallOptions.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to execute the statements against a SQL server DB, there's documentation for using osql.exe  here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa213087%28v=sql.80%29.aspx

You can also open the files in notepad (as one of the comments suggested) and copy and paste from this into your favorite DB Query tool (Query Analyzer for SQL2000, [SQL Server Management Studio](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174173.aspx) or [Visual Studio](http://www.microsoft.com/express/) for SQL Server 2005 and above, or any of the myriad of other tools available)